# Unpacking sources with additional options during the PREP or SETUP stage?

Tags: rpmbuild

I'm working on packaging a library in an RPM. Fedora's RPM Build manual, [8.2.3.2, The PREP Section](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch08s02s03s02.html) states:

> The prep section, short for prepare, defines the commands necessary to prepare for the build. If you are starting with a compressed tar archive (a tarball) of the sources, the prep section needs to extract the sources.
>   For example:
>   `%prep`
>   `%setup -q`
>   The prep section starts with a %prep statement.
>   This example uses the %setup RPM macro, which knows about tar archives, to extract the files. In most cases, this will be all you need in your spec file prep section.

We have a ZIP, and it needs to be extracted with the `-a` option. Otherwise, the patch step fails due to line endings.

How do I pass the `-a` option to the `zip` program through the PREP or SETUP section? (I'm not sure which section or stage needs it, but I know its one of them).

Answer (score 0):

`%prep` is the section of the specfile.

`%setup` is a *macro* within the `%prep` section. You don't need to use it. Take it out and manually write out all the commands you need to unzip the source into a directory named `packagename-versionnumber`.

An example of what `%setup` expands to, along with more options it accepts, can be found [at rpm.org](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-macros.html#S2-RPM-INSIDE-SETUP-MACRO).